# Blackberry <location> lat and lon from googlemaps lat and lon

Tags: blackberry, maps, coordinates

I have coordinates like this:

```
<googlemapsX>32.733611</googlemapsX>

<googlemapsY>-117.189722</googlemapsY>
```

And i want to show them like this:

```
String document = "<lbs>
     <location lat='LAT' lon='LON'/>
     </lbs>";
```

But LAT and LON must be integers, how to convert them?

Comment: Are you using an XML parser to get the first bit?

Comment: I have 2 double values: 32.733611 and -117.189722 and need to convert them to integers to show in <location lat='LAT' lon='LON'/>, my question is how to translate google coord to bb <location lat='LAT' lon='LON'/>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To convert them into the lat/lon that BlackBerry uses in its document, you can just multiply them by 100000 to get the correct value.

```
int lat = 32.733611 * 100000;
int lon = -117.189772 * 100000;
```

And use those values as your LAT and LON

Comment: Is that the same conversion Fixed32 does? http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.1.0api/net/rim/device/api/math/Fixed32.html

Comment: Closer reading of the docs says no: "0x00010000 is the fixed-point representation of 1"

Answer (score 1):

lat, long can be values like 32.733611, -117.189772 (double values)

```
int latitude = (int) (lat * 1e6);
int longitude = (int) (long * 1e6);
```